# PhpStorm shortcut for line breaks

Tags: line, phpstorm, break

Is there a shortcut in PhpStorm for making line breaks?
For example in my previous IDE (Zend studio 5.5) when i'm writing a line and press ctrl+Enter it adds line break tag to the end of the current line and starts new line.

```
## At the end of first line i use shortcut to add line break at the end and start new line
This is first line <br />
This is new line
```

Comment: AFAIK -- No. But you can easily record a Macro or maybe create and use custom Live Template that will do it for you.